# InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found python3.5.2

Tags: python-3.x, httprequest

I'm trying to extract emails from web pages, here is my email grabber function:

```
def emlgrb(x):
    email_set = set()
    for url in x:
        try:
            response = requests.get(url)
            soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
            emails = set(re.findall(r"[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+@[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+\.[a-z]+", soup.text, re.I))
            email_set.update(emails)
        except (requests.exceptions.MissingSchema, requests.exceptions.ConnectionError):
        continue
    return email_set
```

This function should be fed by another function, that creates a list of url. Feeder function:

```
def handle_local_links(url, link):
    if link.startswith("/"):
         return "".join([url, link])
    return link

def get_links(url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
        soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
        body = soup.body
        links = [link.get("href") for link in body.find_all("a")]
        links = [handle_local_links(url, link) for link in links]
        links = [str(link.encode("ascii")) for link in links]
        return links
```

It continues with many exceptions, which if raised - return empty list(not important). However return value from get_links() look like this:

```
["b'https://pythonprogramming.net/parsememcparseface//'"]
```

of course there are many of links in the list(cannot post it - reputation). emlgrb() function is not able to process the list (InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found) However if I manually remove b and redundant quotes - so the list looks like this:

```
['https://pythonprogramming.net/parsememcparseface//']
```

emlgrb() works. Any suggestion where is the problem or haw to create "cleaning function" to get second list from first -  are welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: How does the output look like if you drop .encode('ascii')?

Comment: Actually, works well - thanks.

Comment: I think that in str() you can also specify encoding? If you need that ;)

Comment: I've added answer with some explanation, does that work well? :)

Comment: Sorry for late response. Works exactly as intended. Thanks

Comment: Then please mark my answer as correct ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to drop `.encode('ascii')`

```
def get_links(url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
        soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
        body = soup.body
        links = [link.get("href") for link in body.find_all("a")]
        links = [handle_local_links(url, link) for link in links]
        links = [str(link) for link in links]
        return links
```

You can add coding in `str()` like [in this pydoc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str): `str(object=b'', encoding='utf-8', errors='strict')`

That's because str() calls `.__repr__()` or `.__str__()` on the `object`, thus if it is bytes, then output is `"b'string'"`. Actually that's what gets printed when you do `print(bytes_obj)`. And calling `.ecnode()` on str object creates bytes object!